# Cypress - tests sometimes fail to start in GitLab CI while always running locally

Tags: next.js, gitlab, cypress, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Background - I am creating a Next.js project with MUI and TypeScript. For e2e testing and component testing, I have chosen to use Cypress. I am also using GitLab where I have a simple CI pipeline.

I am getting an error with my Cypress tests while running them in the GitLab pipeline. This error does not occur all the time so if I rerun the pipeline a few times, I always get it to pass eventually. When I run `npm run test` locally, I get no errors.

I have a feeling it is connected to how the image initializes. When files such as core.70 get removed during the setup, the pipeline fails. When other files are removed, it sometimes passes. See the logs for that. I cannot be certain that there is a cousation though, might be a coincidence.

For this run, I have ran the pipeline 4 times in a row with no changes. The first three times I got the same error while the fourth time passed. The behaviouor always changes as sometimes it passes the first time etc.

I can clearly see the error where X or $DISPLAY is missing but since it doesn't happen consistently and I couldn't find anyone else having problems with it (given that they are using the cypress docker images), I would assume it is not a problem on my side (as sometimes I am not missing any dependencies)

[image: screenshot of the pipeline showing that it suddenly passes after multiple runs]

First run log (very similar to second and third runs):

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (436955cb)[0;m
[0K  on Builder 2 sa1k-77p, system ID: s_7635428d789e[0;m
section_start:1684766061:resolve_secrets
[0K[0K[36;1mResolving secrets[0;m[0;m
section_end:1684766061:resolve_secrets
[0Ksection_start:1684766061:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107 ...[0;m
[0KUsing locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:f72e0260bf9d186c75431f774e824dd77b964d370151ac52ef9d7fd7f8bda259 for cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107 with digest cypress/browsers@sha256:bfdbf9b64fdaad364f6e76e3c2a75fbce7c8018644d71e41ef43bba0ae8f4e38 ...[0;m
section_end:1684766065:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1684766065:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
Running on runner-sa1k-77p-project-10579-concurrent-0 via eipbuilder2...
section_end:1684766066:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1684766066:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 20...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in **REDACTED**
[32;1mChecking out 84807f1a as detached HEAD (ref is e2e-new)...[0;m
Removing core.70
Removing core.71
Removing node_modules/

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1684766077:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1684766077:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:f72e0260bf9d186c75431f774e824dd77b964d370151ac52ef9d7fd7f8bda259 for cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107 with digest cypress/browsers@sha256:bfdbf9b64fdaad364f6e76e3c2a75fbce7c8018644d71e41ef43bba0ae8f4e38 ...[0;m
[32;1m$ npm ci[0;m

added 555 packages, and audited 556 packages in 1m

172 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
[32;1m$ npm run test[0;m

> training-platform-frontend@0.1.0 test
> cypress run --component --browser chrome --headless

[STARTED] Task without title.
[FAILED] Cypress failed to start.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Please refer to the error below for more details.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] [71:0522/143550.440517:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[FAILED] [71:0522/143550.440614:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.5)
[FAILED] Cypress Version: 12.12.0
Cypress failed to start.

This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

Please refer to the error below for more details.

----------

[71:0522/143550.440517:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[71:0522/143550.440614:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

----------

Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.5)
Cypress Version: 12.12.0
section_end:1684766153:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1684766153:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up project directory and file based variables[0;m[0;m
section_end:1684766154:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

Fourth run log:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (436955cb)[0;m
[0K  on Builder 1 baaac080, system ID: s_cb29ef96823f[0;m
section_start:1684766184:resolve_secrets
[0K[0K[36;1mResolving secrets[0;m[0;m
section_end:1684766184:resolve_secrets
[0Ksection_start:1684766184:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107 ...[0;m
[0KUsing locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:f72e0260bf9d186c75431f774e824dd77b964d370151ac52ef9d7fd7f8bda259 for cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107 with digest cypress/browsers@sha256:bfdbf9b64fdaad364f6e76e3c2a75fbce7c8018644d71e41ef43bba0ae8f4e38 ...[0;m
section_end:1684766184:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1684766184:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
Running on runner-baaac080-project-10579-concurrent-0 via eipbuilder1...
section_end:1684766185:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1684766185:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 20...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in **REDACTED**
[32;1mChecking out 84807f1a as detached HEAD (ref is e2e-new)...[0;m
Removing .next/
Removing next-env.d.ts
Removing node_modules/

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1684766191:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1684766191:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:f72e0260bf9d186c75431f774e824dd77b964d370151ac52ef9d7fd7f8bda259 for cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107 with digest cypress/browsers@sha256:bfdbf9b64fdaad364f6e76e3c2a75fbce7c8018644d71e41ef43bba0ae8f4e38 ...[0;m
[32;1m$ npm ci[0;m

added 555 packages, and audited 556 packages in 50s

172 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
[32;1m$ npm run test[0;m

> training-platform-frontend@0.1.0 test
> cypress run --component --browser chrome --headless

[STARTED] Task without title.
[SUCCESS] Task without title.
```

This is my pipeline configuration:

```
# Test Stage
test:
    image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
    script:
        - npm ci
        - npm run test
```

With this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "cypress run --component --browser chrome --headless",
  },
```

cypress.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            // implement node event listeners here
        },
        excludeSpecPattern: ['**/examples/**/*'],
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
        video: false,
    },

    component: {
        devServer: {
            framework: 'next',
            bundler: 'webpack',
        },
        video: false,
    },
});
```

I have looked over the Continuous Integration section on the Cypress website.

I have tried different images such as `cypress/base:latest` or `node:latest` but none of them worked better. I have also tried to add `undet DISPLAY` which was recommended somewhere but to no avail.

I have tried omitting the `--headless` or the browsers etc.

Comment: With docker executors, sometimes `/dev/shm` space can be an issue. Using the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag (might be different depending on the browser) may help.

Comment: The cypress changelog for version 6.0.0 says that they pass the flag to the chrome browser by default now